# What specific updates were made in April in the Pine language?

Tags: pine-script

I seem to feel that there have been some changes in strategy backtesting, particularly regarding trailing stop loss.
In my backtesting, there wasn't much change in tracking stop-losses for currencies with higher prices. However, for some currencies with lower prices, all backtesting results have turned from profit to loss. I'm not sure if there has been a change in the logic calculation method for tracking stop-losses in backtesting, or if it's the calculation method for the tracking stop-loss strategy itself. I'm a bit panicked about this change.

I hope someone can answer what updates were made in the Pine language in April.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/Release_notes.html#april-2023

```
Fixed an issue with trailing stops in strategy.exit() being filled on high/low prices rather than on intrabar prices.
```